# Can I trust Perl to rename before I overwrite?

Tags: perl, rename

Can I really trust that rename will be done before I put a new file in the old location?  If not what is the better way to do this?  Do I (-e test.old) to make sure it's been moved or is that unnecessary?

```
rename("test", "test.old") || die "Can't rename test";

open(FILE, ">test") || die "Can't write to test";
print FILE "foo";
close(FILE);
```

Comment: operating system?  might test.old exist?

Answer (score 2):

There are many things that can make the rename fail, so an addition of `if (-e "test") { die "File not renamed beforehand!\n" }` is a cheap insurance policy.

In your case, i can honestly not think of a reason for the rename to fail without triggering the `die` condition you already have, but if an overwrite would be catastrophic an extra disk read as safeguard is probably still worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Also can't think of any reasons why your `or die` wouldn't catch anything from going wrong with [`rename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html).  Heck, I'd be content to rely on [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html).

However, perlfaq5 and [`How come when I open a file read-write it wipes it out?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-come-when-I-open-a-file-read-write-it-wipes-it-out%3f) has another method for doing a sanity check.

If you want to open file for writing, create new file, **file must not exist**, then you can use [`sysopen`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen.html):

```
use Fcntl;

sysopen my $fh, $path, O_WRONLY|O_EXCL|O_CREAT or die $!;
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Can I really trust that rename will be done before I put a new file in the old location?*

Yes. The `unlink(2)` is always called before `rename` returns.

The OS might not have committed that change to disk, so a power outage at that very moment could in theory "undelete" the file.

But even then, `open` won't overwrite the exiting file since the OS works from a view of things as it would be if they had been committed to disk.